# Python Map and Filter code that operates on lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to use map and filter to operates on lists db, and dc.

```
db = [3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9] 
dc = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

to produce the output list of **`dd = [25,9,49]`**  i.e., element of db is squared if
the corresponding entry in dc is a 0.

Here's what I have so far.

```
db = [3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9]
dc = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
dd = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, filter(lambda y: y == 0, dc)))
print(dd)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right direction would probably be to not use `filter` but `zip`:

```
db = [3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9]
dc = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

dd = [b**2 for b,c in zip(db, dc) if not c]
```

Output: `[25,9,49]`

##### using `filter`

This requires to find a common ground, here the index, but the code is much less nicer...

```
list(map(lambda x: db[x]**2,  filter(lambda y: dc[y]==0, range(len(dc)))))
```

Comment: I like your solution @mozway, but the question requires to use filter and map to solve the problem

Comment: Check the update @Ricky but honestly, this is not as clean as the other. Can you use `zip`?

Comment: Sounds like a HW problem, but why can't y'all just use *both* `filter` and `zip` then?

Comment: @mtraceur thus my question

Comment: I already did a similar one using zip @mozway